# How to change a line in a text file with echo?

Tags: linux, unix, grep, echo, cat

Let's say we have a file named `profile.cfg` containing the following:

```
user.name=Duvdevan
user.email=duvdevan@duvdevan.duv
user.web=http://duvdevan.duv
user.country=Bosnia/Herzegovina
user.age=26
user.biography="A web developer.\n\nLikes echo command..."
```

Now, I'd like to update contents of line three, the `user.web` property and place it in the same position as it is currently to keep above and bellow contents as they are.

All I have tried so far is: `cat profile.cfg | grep user.web` and I get the value of that line...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this easily using `sed`

```
$ sed 's#user.web=.*#user.web=http://NEW_DOMAIN#' file
user.name=Duvdevan
user.email=duvdevan@duvdevan.duv
user.web=http://NEW_DOMAIN
user.country=Bosnia/Herzegovina
user.age=26
user.biography="A web developer.\n\nLikes echo command..."
```

Use `-i` option to make inline changes to file so that no redirection is required.